# the number of columns (1) does not match the number of columns in the referenced key (2)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

[image]

I created an FK from my tale TB_ATTENDANCE but there was an error:

```
Error code 30000, SQL state X0Y43: Constraint 'SQL141012204300440' is invalid: the number of columns (1) does not match the number of columns in the referenced key (2).
```

and here's my statement:

```
ALTER TABLE TB_ATTENDANCE ADD FOREIGN KEY(EMP_ID) REFERENCES TB_EMPLOYEE;
```

could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References TB_EMPLOYEE on which field? You must specify it.

```
ALTER TABLE TB_ATTENDANCE
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TB_EMPLOYEE_EMP_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID)
REFERENCES TB_EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID);
```

Comment: It's still the same.. `there is no unique or primary key constraint on table '"ORLY"."TB_EMPLOYEE"' that matches the number and types of the columns in the foreign key.` 

and I'm sure that the FK has the same type with its reference.

Comment: `Syntax error: Encountered "ADD" at line 1, column 64.`
Nothing happens

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped two 'ADD's, please try now.

Comment: same error again: `there is no unique or primary key constraint on table '"ORLY"."TB_EMPLOYEE"' that matches the number and types of the columns in the foreign key.` I don't know why.

Comment: I think It's because that the EMP_ID in the TB_EMPLOYEE is auto increment. Don't you think sir?

Comment: Are both fields extactly the same type (int)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62921/discussion-between-orly-and-bernardolima).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed to specify the reference table column name in your query.

Comment: what do you mean sir?